# The tag [adf] is ambiguous and is asking to be Burninated/Synonymized

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags, synonym-request

While looking through the Suggested Edits queue, I stumbled upon the tag [adf](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/adf) whose tag wiki begins:

> DO NOT USE THIS TAG! Use [oracle-adf](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/oracle-adf) instead

Questions appear to be divided between describing 2 distinct technologies: Microsoft `Azure Data Factory` and Oracle `Application Development Framework`, each of which has their own tags: [azure-data-factory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/azure-data-factory) and [oracle-adf](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/oracle-adf).

- **Does it describe the contents of the questions to which it is applied? and is it unambiguous?**

  - No, I see questions referencing `Azure Data Factory`, Oracle `Application Development Framework`, `Alfresco Application Development Framework`, and `Area Description File`. It seems to be a meta-tag that is only meaningful in combination with other tags.
- **Is the concept described even on-topic for the site?**

  - Yes
- **Does the tag add any meaningful information to the post?**

  - No. Alone it's meaningless, and with the appropriate clarifying tags, it doesn't add anything.
- **Does it mean the same thing in all common contexts?**

  - No, depending on the presence of other tags it could refer to either the `Azure Data Factory` and Oracle `Application Development Framework`

I can't say it's a high priority, but it seems to me that this should either be burninated or be made a synonym of [oracle-adf](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/oracle-adf), and questions related to [azure-data-factory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/azure-data-factory) should be retagged.

**UPDATE**: All the tags have been cleared out and the tag wiki has been deleted. So I guess that's it: Mission Accomplished, Everybody!

Comment: I think what you want is a [synonym-request]. Burninate is for removing tags inviting bad questions. Most of the [adf] questions seem on-topic

Comment: Uh, didn't the edit just invalidate the answer by pnuts? The answer was clearly disagreeing with the burnination before it was changed completely to make it a synonym request.

Comment: @BhargavRao Sorry, I changed it in response to the comment by Machavity which raised a good point about making it a synonym rather than a burnination

Comment: @Machavity's comment should have been an answer instead, disagreeing with burnination and requesting synonymization instead... but now meh, pnuts has deleted their answer.... so I guess it's fine? (I'm not sure as well)

Comment: I was under the impression that ambiguity intermediately made a tag ineligible for synonimization, because, hey the tag means two things and you can only synonym to one.

Comment: @BhargavRao come on! Not here! I can still disagree with pnuts answer without reading the question!

Comment: @Braiam, I'm referring to pnuts' now deleted answer, not the current one.

Comment: @BhargavRao well, the system worked as intended: OP figured that its query was incomplete or otherwise unsuitable, modified the question to make sure the query was accurate. Answeres should have make sure that their understanding of the content of the question match the OP's

Comment: Which is why I mentioned that it was fine now, @Braiam.

Comment: For what it's worth, if we have any questions about avionics programming, this could also be conceivably confused with [Automated Direction Finder](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Radio_direction_finder#Automatic_direction_finder_(ADF)).

Comment: Do we know that this tag is used enough to refer to the Oracle framework over everything else that it should be a synonym rather than just being removed/blacklisted or similar? To me, it seems like ADF has too many different meanings to reasonably be a synonym of anything, but I could be wrong.

Comment: @BhargavRao that's the problem, it shouldn't even be mentioned. You don't need anyone to even consider such thing. It's a chilling effect.

Comment: @reirab That's the most common usage, but there are a few others: `azure-data-factory` and `Alfresco Application Development Framework` being the ones I've found so far. I'm inclined to agree with pnuts that it's to ambiguous to use and the short form tags should be removed

Comment: The tag was [recreated today](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54802564/small-size-sample-10-observations-unit-root-test) to refer to the "Augmented Dickey–Fuller test"

Comment: @BhargavRao Thanks, I took care of that. The question was off-topic anyway

Answer (score 11, accepted):

*Questions appear to be divided between describing 2 distinct technologies: Microsoft `Azure Data Factory` and Oracle `Application Development Framework`, each of which has their own tags: [azure-data-factory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/azure-data-factory) and [oracle-adf](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/oracle-adf).*

Which seems fairly certain to mean that if [adf](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/adf) (currently <strike>249</strike> **0** Qs) is made a synonym for *either* it will be misapplied to *the other* - so [adf](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/adf) should indeed not be used (as too prone to ambiguity).

For example <strike>31</strike> **0** Open Qs tagged [adf](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/adf) mention `azure`. Even if *all* the others (~<strike>218</strike> **0**) turn out to be eligible for [oracle-adf](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/oracle-adf) the task of renaming is not beyond being solved 'manually', which in the circumstances would be safer than a synonymisation.

However it would disappear 'of its own accord' if the relevant 'long-form' tags are applied in place of [adf](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/adf) and such a clean up would be part of the burninantion process anyway, so burninantion is not required.

[azure-data-factory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/azure-data-factory) <strike>912</strike> 917 Open Qs.

Both [azure-data-factory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/azure-data-factory) and [adf](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/adf) <strike>8</strike> **0** Qs.

[oracle-adf](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/oracle-adf) <strike>1,725</strike> 1,865 Open Qs.

Both [oracle-adf](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/oracle-adf) and [adf](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/adf) <strike>71</strike> **0** Qs.

A synonym [adf](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/adf) → [oracle-adf](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/oracle-adf) was proposed more than 5 years ago and has received a net 2 votes in favour so far. There are dozens of subject matter experts eligible to vote and the Usage guide for [adf](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/adf) even asks that they do:

> DO NOT USE THIS TAG! Use [oracle-adf] instead. If possible, vote for the tag synonym as well http://stackoverflow.com/tags/oracle-adf/synonyms

If SMEs are content with the current status the rest of our Community should leave them be without imposing a synonym. However the ambiguity is of relevance to the rest of our Community and therefore should be addressed - by removing the 'short-from' version where used in conjunction with 'long-form' (and not appropriate) and by replacing the 'short-form' version with the appropriate 'long-form' version (or versions).

This is routine cleaning up that does not require mod intervention.

Comment: Ok, so then would the answer be to just make the required retags instead of involving meta?

Comment: @divibisan It involves mass retagging, so I think we'd have to get Meta sanction for it (rather than just unilaterally doing it).