# Is there guidance on tag disambiguation?

Tags: support, tags, meta, tag-disambiguation

The process for tag-burnination is [well-documented](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/324070/what-is-the-process-for-tag-removal-burnination). Is there similar guidance for creating a disambiguation request?

I found a tag which requires disambiguation. I am struggling to find any information about how to properly make the request. As a <2K user, should I be even bothering with this, since I lack the ability to do efficient tag-maintainance?

Comment: As a <2k user re-tagging lots of question is only going to annoy reviewers. Do know that we're currently in a process to handle the backlog of burninate requests. We touch disambiguation in those cases as well but we're not yet on an established process and I doubt if, given the only 202 questions, that is even needed.

Comment: You can **create** a disambiguation request regardless of reputation, although **fulfilling** it by editing questions is a different story.

Comment: I think it's worth raising on Meta if you think you see a problem even if you can't actually do any of the editing yourself.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Tag disambiguation is a highly 'manual' activity and not susceptible to automation. As such the process is very little different from other routine retagging which could be for reasons others than disambiguation.

One difference however can be the volume involved. Applying the [java] tag to what is clearly a JavaScript Q can be addressed in isolation from other tags on other Qs. However unscrambling for example the [flash](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/flash) applications ([see](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/372957/this-tag-is-a-flash-in-the-pan)) may involve over 35,000 Qs. So whereas an edit suggestion from a below 2K user might be welcome for the former example it is probably better that only 2k+ users are at all heavily involved with the latter.

Disambiguation also differs from a routine single retag because consideration should probably be given as to whether one tag should be split into several (effectively "burninating" that single tag) or whether the single tag would be better preserved and only some instances retagged.

For example for [adf](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/adf)  it was decided (see [here](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/372817/the-tag-adf-is-ambiguous-and-is-asking-to-be-burninated-synonymized)) that retention of [adf](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/adf) would invite continuing problems hence all uses were allocated different tags (none [adf](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/adf)).

For [flash](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/flash) a different approach may be taken, albeit with a switch of  synonyms making the process more complicated than keeping the single tag unchanged and only retagging where misapplied.

There was a request to burninate the [fix](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/fix) tag on the grounds of [ambiguity](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/371594/the-fix-is-broken):

> In the first page of results, only half of them are actually related to the FIX Protocol. Everything else is just some guy looking for a "fix" to their problem.

In this case however, so far, a very modest amount of retagging or closure of those Qs that were just looking for "fixes" has been considered sufficient disambiguation. For the time being at least [fix](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/fix) lives on. At the time of that burnination request there were 398 Open Qs so tagged, and less than one month later, and after disambiguation, there are still 390.

The proper way to make a disambiguation request is as a post on meta and it is helpful to be made aware of such issues even if that is by someone unable efficiently to do very much about them themselves. (Indeed more so than by a high rep user who could be getting on with the work themselves instead of coming here to ask others to do so instead.)  However high or low reputation should not prevent a good case being made. For example by including relevant statistics.